# searching inside an array for a value

Tags: javascript

Morning Guys

im currently playing with javascript and am creating a simple black jack game, i want to keep track of cards which have already been pulled from the pack. heres my function

```
function usedCards(value,suit)
{
var exists = false;

for(i = 0; i< usedCardNo.length;i++)
  {
    if (value === usedCardNo[i] && suit === usedCardSuit[i])
         {
            exists = true;
            console.log(i);         
         } 
  }
    console.log("exists = " + exists);

if (exists===false)
         {
             usedCardNo.push(value);
             usedCardSuit.push(suit);
             console.log(value + " and " + suit +" added to array");        
          } 
}
```

i pass the function 2 id numbers one realting to card number ie ace, 7, 9 aswell as suit.

i then check if it already exists in the array, if not add it. but its not currently working?? it just doesnt recognise a duplicate value.

Comment: fix your parenthesis first !.

Comment: Verify your code with http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are comparing values of the same type in the loop? `"12" !== 12`

Answer (score 1):

Mhm however your code seems to work for me. Have a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SY8Nh/). It seems to show the expected output:

```
exists = false
1 and 2 added to array
exists = false
3 and 7 added to array
0
exists = true
```

What you maybe experiencing is that the function does not return anything right now. So you have to add `return exists;` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix several things:

```
function usedCards(value,suit){ 
    var exists = false; 
    for(i = 0; i< usedCardNo.length;i++){ 
        if (value == usedCardNo[i] && suit == usedCardSuit[i]){ 
            exists = true; 
            console.log(i);
         }   
    } 
    console.log("exists = " + exists); 
    if (exists==false){ 
    usedCardNo.push(value); 
    usedCardSuit.push(suit); 
    console.log(value + " and " + suit +" added to array");
    }
}
```

Comment: Mhm all you changed is the equals operator. It's not a bad idea to use === at all so why should this be changed?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry! Could you highlight what you changed?

Answer (score 0):

Using an array to continuously check if something is in there is a bad idea. What you actually want to be using is a map. Something along the lines of:

```
var used_cards = {};
function useCard(value, suit) {
  var key = suit + '|' + value;
  if (used_cards[key]) {
    return false;
  }

  used_cards[key] = true;
  return true;
}
```